# Can someone identify this gate pillar mounting?

Tags: hinges, brackets, gates, gate-post

As in the question title, I have these brackets mounted in the pillars at the front of my driveway. Can anyone tell me what I am supposed to attach to them in order to mount gates or some-such?

[image: Gate post hinge]

Comment: Are they threaded inside?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: Gates OR some-such ?

Comment: They are not threaded, which is what puzzled me even more!

Comment: it looks an awful lot like a sleeve nut, double check for that thread, it might start some distance down the hole.